# PROBLEM WITH required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, autowired, spring-security-oauth2

When launching with mvn spring-boot:run or even with gradle returns that issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userDetailsService in com.ess.study.jwt.integration.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' in 'UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' authenticationManager


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.
```

Here are the main classes, all the requirements looks ok to me, I am using the org.springframework.boot release 2.0.6.RELEASE.RELEASE

```
package com.ess.study.jwt.integration.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity // Habilita la seguridad de Spring y consejos Spring Boot para aplicar todos los
                    // valores predeterminados sensibles
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // Nos permite tener control de acceso a nivel de método.
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer encodingStrength;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(encodingStrength));
    }


    @Autowired
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic()
                .realmName(securityRealm).and().csrf().disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary // Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token
                // service instance of the same name
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    //Nuevo metodo de decodificación.

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

and:

```
package com.ess.study.jwt.integration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StudySecuredApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudySecuredApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Using maven or gradle it returns the same issue. All annotations and packages names seems to be as required.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

**UserDetailsService** is an interface and you have to create its implementation. Example:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            User user = usersRepository.findByLogin(login).get();
            return new UserPrincipal(usersRepository.findByLogin(login).get());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + login + " not found.", e);
        }
    }

}
```